# How to setup nerd font glyphs for VSCode terminal using oh-my-zsh and starship?

Tags: ubuntu, visual-studio-code, zsh, wsl-2, oh-my-zsh

I've recently installed `WSL2`, `oh-my-zsh`, `Hack NerdFont` and there-after tried to install [starship](https://starship.rs/) based on [vscode](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/terminal/appearance) to make my vscode terminal look like this:
[image]

Currently it looks like this:

[image]

Is there any configurations that I missed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is [preset](https://starship.rs/presets/#nerd-font-symbols) section that has some themes on it and you can apply them by these instructions:

1. [Pastel PowerLine](https://starship.rs/presets/#pastel-powerline)

```
starship preset pastel-powerline > ~/.config/starship.toml
```

[image]

2.[Tokyo Night](https://starship.rs/presets/tokyo-night.html)

```
starship preset tokyo-night > ~/.config/starship.toml
```

[image]

Also there is a very good alternative to `starship` and it is [powerlevel10k](https://github.com/romkatv/powerlevel10k) it has a really smooth and step by step instruction that you can follow to install

```
1. Clone the repository:
git clone --depth=1 https://github.com/romkatv/powerlevel10k.git ${ZSH_CUSTOM:-$HOME/.oh-my-zsh/custom}/themes/powerlevel10k

2. Set `ZSH_THEME="powerlevel10k/powerlevel10k"` in `~/.zshrc`.
```

[image]